How to enable switching users with Plasma using LightDM as Display Manager?
Since SDDM doesn't support changing expired passwords, I need to switch to something else that does, and I decided to try LightDM.
On Kubuntu 24.04 or 22.04, how do I make "switch user" work with LightDM?
Right now, it just brings me to Plasma's lockscreen.
